# When Click on Navigation Bar Tableview scroll with Refresh Control in Swift 4 iOS

Tags: swift, uitableview, uinavigationbar, swift4, uirefreshcontrol

When I click on NavigationBar, my tableview is scrolled but the issue is it also scroll refresh control ! How can I scroll my tableview only, but not RefreshControl?

[image]

```
    @objc func handleRefresh(_ refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {

        let newHotel = Hotels(name: "Montage Laguna Beach", place: "California south")
        hotels.append(newHotel)

        hotels.sort() { $0.name < $1.place }

        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()

    }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setupSearchBar(searchController: searchController, tableView: tableView)
        self.tableView.addSubview(self.refreshControl)
    }

 func setupSearchBar(searchController: UISearchController, tableView: UITableView){
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self as? UISearchResultsUpdating
        searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
        if #available(iOS 9.1, *) {
            searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        } else {
        }
        definesPresentationContext = true
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
            navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        } else {
            tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
        }
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self as? UISearchBarDelegate
    }

  lazy var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl = {
        let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleRefresh(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
        refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.red
        return refreshControl
    }()
```

Comment: Can you please tell me why this question is downvote .?

Comment: Please add code about what you try?

Comment: Hello Please check now